# How to use isElementPresent/isPresent inside ng-repeat in protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <span><input ng-model="todo.title" /></span>
        <span><input ng-model="todo.time" /></span>
        <span><input ng-model="todo.name" /></span>
</div>
```

Passing test:

```
expect(element(by.repeater('todo in todos')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Passing test:

```
expect(element(by.repeater('todo in todos').row(1)).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Failing test 1:

> Expected false to be true.

```
expect(element(by.repeater('todo in todos').row(1).column('todo.name')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Failed test 2:

> Expected false to be true.

```
browser.isElementPresent(element(by.repeater('todo in todos').row(1).column('todo.name'))).then(function(present){
    expect(present).toBe(true);
})
```

At item level I can set data in field. At item level I can retrieve data in field. But not able to use `isPresent` or `isElementPresent` at item level?

Comment: You don't have anything in the HTML that is bound to `todo.name`. Only `todo.title` and `todo.time`.

Comment: there are two inputs controls in html

Comment: And is any of them bound to `todo.name`? Have you **read** my comment?

Comment: @JB Nizet : i have made mistake in writing question .i have updated it.to make i more simple and i have changed the name to normal ones.Also in html i have added todo.name

Comment: thanks @JBNizet thanks for editing question and pointing out error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it Working ! This code will `sendKeys` only if input is present.

I debugged this Code in webstorm and did this:

```
element.all(by.repeater('todo in todos')).then(function(allrows){

    for(var i = 0 ;i<allrows.length ;i++)
    {
        allrows[i].all(by.model('todo.name')).then(function(field){

            field[0].isPresent().then(function(val){

                expect(val).toBe(true);

                field[0].sendKeys('22.335');

            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, you have to manually use `by.model()` locator. `column()` is using "by binding". Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that [`.column('todo.name')`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/8b77fd836b039965722e01e83c0e71b36bf881f6/lib/locators.js#L254) would search for elements *bound to `todo.name`*. In other words, it would make a search *by binding* (see [`findRepeaterElement`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6c10378b9a4e7cae9ba491a63ae11f942c833100/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L221)), while you have `todo.name` defined as an `ng-model`.

Quoting @juliemr (issue [ng-repeat with ng-model bindings](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/147)):

> the column selector takes a string which matches bindings, not input ng-models.

Comment: @plutopunch yeah, but my point is still valid and it explains the behavior.